# Vbscript / HTA - Adding some background color ou background image and a top logo

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a working vbscript form with some parts based on hta code. 
The form is intended to open a incident in a ticketing tool. This is also working as expected.
I intend to do some adjustments, specially adding a background wallpaper or changing color, and also adding a logo (in jpg ou png) on the top left corner of the form. I think this can be changed on the hta part of the script but I tried to apply some modifications, so far without success.

Below is the code. Any clue? Thank you very much.

```
Sub GetParams(sTitle, sPrompt, oParams, bAccepted, iWidth, iHeight) 
Dim oWnd, sContent, aKeys, i 
sContent = "<div style='font: 8pt tahoma;'>" 
aKeys = oParams.Keys 
For i = 0 To oParams.Count - 1 
sContent = sContent & "<span style='margin: 4px;'>" & HtmlSafe(aKeys(i)) & "</span><br>" 
sContent = sContent & "<input id=textbox" & i & " value='" & HtmlSafe(oParams.Item(aKeys(i))) & "' type='textbox' style='font: 8pt tahoma; width: 100%; margin: 4px;'/><br>" 
Next 
sContent = sContent & "<br><input onclick='window.accepted=true;' type='button' value='Criar' style='font: 8pt tahoma; width: 75px; height: 21px; float: right; margin-right: 20px;'/></div>" 
Set oWnd = CreateWindow() 
With oWnd 
With .Document 
.Title = sTitle 
.Body.Style.Background = "buttonface" 
.Body.InnerHtml = sContent 
End With 
.ResizeTo iWidth, iHeight 
.MoveTo CInt((.Screen.AvailWidth - iWidth) / 2), CInt((.Screen.AvailHeight - iHeight) / 2) 
End With 
oWnd.ExecScript "var accepted=false;" 
On Error Resume Next 
Do 
bAccepted = oWnd.Accepted 
If bAccepted Then Exit Do 
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
bAccepted = False 
Exit Sub 
End If 
WScript.Sleep 10 
Loop 
For i = 0 To oParams.Count - 1 
oParams(aKeys(i)) = oWnd.Document.GetElementById("textbox" & i).Value 
Next 
oWnd.Close 
End Sub 

Function HtmlSafe(sText) 
HtmlSafe = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(sText, "&", "&amp;"), "<", "&lt;"), ">", "&gt;"), vbCrLf, "<br>") 
End Function 

Function CreateWindow() 
Dim sSignature, oShellWnd, oProc 
sSignature = Left(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").Guid, 38) 
Set oProc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("mshta ""about:<html><head><script>moveTo(-32000,-32000);document.title=' '</script><hta:application id=app border=thick minimizebutton=no maximizebutton=no scroll=no showintaskbar=yes contextmenu=no selection=no innerborder=no icon=""""/><object id='shell' classid='clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'><param name=RegisterAsBrowser value=1></object><script>shell.putproperty('" & sSignature & "',document.parentWindow);</script></head></html>""") 
Do 
If oProc.Status > 0 Then 
Set CreateWindow = Nothing 
Exit Function 
End If 
For Each oShellWnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows 
On Error Resume Next 
Set CreateWindow = oShellWnd.GetProperty(sSignature) 
If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Function 
On Error Goto 0 
Next 
Loop 
End Function
```

Comment: Please do not broadcast your questions without at least giving note of [where else you asked](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/fb.ashx?m=106016).

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't know I had to do that. I'm afraid I have to extend your list then. :D

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to include the image with your script, not reference one that already exists on disk. You can use CSS for that. Define the `background-image` property with a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) like this:

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,<base64-encoded image>);
```

Example data URI for a red 1px PNG image:

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3goaER0v2K3gpwAAABl0RVh0Q29tbWVudABDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggR0lNUFeBDhcAAAAMSURBVAjXY/jPwAAAAwEBABjdjbAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
```

If you don't have a tool for converting stuff to base64 you can use an [online converter](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter).

Repetition of images is controlled via the `background-repeat` property. For including a logo you could make the logo the background of a `<div>` with repetition set to `no-repeat`.

If you define the style in a `<style></style>` block you need to specify a selector, e.g.:

```
<style>
body {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...);
}
</style>
```

Otherwise you'll have to put it in the `style` attribute of a tag, e.g.:

```
<body style="background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...);">
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, but unfortunately that doesn't work. And it doesn't work either repeating what you just told me not to broadcast from someplace else ;)

Comment: @Malbordio People here ought to know what answers you already received, so that they don't waste their time on suggesting something that already had been suggested. And FTR: it does work if you do it right. Which you didn't.

Comment: So you call that a waist of time? I would share what I found out once I know, so if I find the answer someplace else I would share it here, and I can bet many people will be greatful, much more than the ones that think it is a waist of time doing that. Anyway, thinking that way is up to you. :)